# Prove for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a positive integer $k$, such that, $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} a_n < \varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ be a convergent series. Prove for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a positive integer $k$, such that, $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} a_n < \varepsilon$.

Forgive me for I am weak at analysis, I do know I can use Cauchy's criterion for convergence, but I do not know how to start.

Comment: are all a_n supposed to be positive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows directly from the Cauchy criterion coupled with the theorem that "Convergent series $\Leftrightarrow$ Cauchy Criterion".

The cauchy criterion states:
For $(a_n)\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ that's cauchy$:\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists N\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $n\geq k > N \Rightarrow |\sum\limits_{i=k}^{n} a_i| < \varepsilon$.

So if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} a_i$ convergent, then the Cauchy Criterion holds, and thus $\sum\limits_{i=k}^{n} a_i \leq |\sum\limits_{i=k}^{n} a_i| < \varepsilon$ considering there could be nonpositive elements in our sequence $(a_n)$.

But since it holds for all $n\geq k > N$ we have what we were trying to prove, there's a $k\in \mathbb{N}: \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum\limits_{i=k}^{n} a_i  < \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be the value of the sum. Note for given $\epsilon > 0$ and $N$ large enough

$$ L - \epsilon < \sum_{i=0}^N a_i $$

But

$$\sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty} a_i + \sum_{i=0}^N a_i = L$$

so

$$\sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty} a_i < \epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the   "truncation error" $R_m:=\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty a_k$ as a function of $m$ doesn't make sense unless you have proven that the implied series actually converges.

Let $s_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k$ $(n\geq0)$ be the partial sums of the original series, and let $s$ be its sum. Then for all $N\geq m$ we have
$$\sum_{k=m+1}^N a_k=s_N-\sum_{k=0}^m a_k=s_N-s_m\ .$$
Letting $N\to\infty$ here we see that the "truncation error"
$$R_m:=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=m+1}^N a_k=s-s_m\tag{1}$$
actually "exists", and has the expected value. Letting $m\to\infty$ in $(1)$ proves your claim since $\lim_{m\to\infty} s_m=s$.